# how to simulate the hover of cursor python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, hover

I want to click on button on web site, but this button appears after you put your cursor on the right place, otherwise you can not see this button. I tried to ignore that and do just normal click by finding the element by xpath. But that did not work out, there was mistake:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not
interactable: element has zero size

How to deal with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hover over the element you can use something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome= webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get('http://foo.bar')
element = chrome.find_element_by_css_selector("the_element_u_want")

hover = ActionChains(chrome).move_to_element(element)
hover.perform()
```

if the element takes time to appear use selenium's [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) or [time.sleep()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep)

find more info about ActionChains [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html)

Comment: I still have a problem. For clearness: here is a web site I am talking about - https://vk.com/durov?z=photo1_456311217%2Fphotos1, I want to click on the button which is switching the images to the right(looks like ">")

Comment: But for some reason my code is not working, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

this is some code I found [here](http://allselenium.info/wait-for-elements-python-selenium-webdriver/).

Usually, the ElementNotInteractableException is thrown when the element hasn't loaded completely. Here's a possible solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\dell\\Libs\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("http://url")
driver.maximize_window()

# wait for element to appear, then hover it
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
men_menu = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-tracking-id='men']")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(men_menu).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

This method worked well for me.

```
def hoverXPATH(xpath):
   item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)\
   .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).perform()
```